# Why is the ubuntu desktop displayed on a remote desktop different that the "real one" using XRDP?

Tags: remote-desktop

Running ubuntu 21.04 on raspberry pi 4 8GB.  Remoting in from Win10 pro PC via Microsoft RDP, XRDP installed on raspberry.
When I use MS RDP to another Windows machine, the remote presentation is an exact mirror of the remote PC.  When I use MS RDP to the raspberry pi, I do not get a mirror image but something altogether different.[PC remote view of pi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azoj8.png)[PC remote view of pi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKsW7.png)
Minimize buttons are gone, the dock has to be called up, etc.  Anyway to get it to behave and look like the real desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess here...How did you perform the installation of xRDP on your raspberry box ?  If you have opened a command line and issue the following command

`sudo apt-get install xrdp`

The basic functionality will be there.  However, if you want to be presented similar desktop interface, you need to perform some post customization actions

Assuming that you are using the **Gnome Desktop interface** on your Ubuntu Pi machine, you can fix the issue by creating a login script file by issuing the following command in a terminal session

```
cat <<EOF > ~/.xsessionrc
echo export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg
EOF
```

After the file is created, login back to xRDP session and see if the desktop look like the one you have when logged on locally.

Another option for your next installation could be to use a script installer that perform the post configuration actions when installing xRDP software. You can always give it a try and see if this could run on Raspberry Pi boxes. The script and how to guide can be found here  (see http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=17175)

Please note that the script is updated on a regular base, so please be sure to check if a new version of the script is available...